# What Is The Smallest Solution to $7x^5=11y^{13}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started teaching myself Number Theory from a pretty basic textbook and I got completely stuck with this problem.

Let $x$ and $y$ be two non-zero natural numbers such that $7x^5=11y^{13}$ .
The lowest possible value for $x$ has a prime factorization of the form $a^cb^d$ . What's the value of the sum $a+b+c+d$ ?

Can anyone show a solution ? I'm much more interested in the way of thinking rather than the result.

Comment: Hint: Since $7$ and $11$ are primes, you have, for equality in equation to hold, $11\mid x$ and $7\mid y$. Now, minimize value of $x$ using this condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From $7x^5 = 11y^{13}$, we have that $11$ divides $x$ and $7$ divides $y$. Let $x=7^a 11^b m$ and $y=7^c11^dn$, where $$\gcd(m,7)=\gcd(m,11)=\gcd(n,7)=\gcd(n,11)=1$$
This gives us that
$$7^{5a+1}11^{5b}m^5 = 7^{13c}11^{13d+1}n^{13}$$
This means $5a+1=13c$, $5b=13d+1$ and $m^5=n^{13}$. Since we are after the smallest possible $x$, we have $m=n=1$, $a=5,c=2$ and $b=8,d=3$. This gives us that
$$x=7^5\cdot11^8$$

Comment: really cool approach, thank you!

Comment: @gnometorule his $c,d$ is different from my $c,d$. Kindly read the answer in detail before commenting.

Comment: Why can you say $x=7^a11^bm$ I mean: Why is 7 a factor of $x$?
Also, why are all those gcd's equal to 1? Sorry, trying to understand your answer as this problem interests me too.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Note that if $7$ divides $y^{13}$, then $7$ divides $y$, i.e., $7^{13}$ divides $y^{13}$. This means $7^{13}$ has to divide $x^5 \implies 7$ divides $x^5 \implies 7$ divides $x$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD We are essentially pulling out all multiples of $7$ and $11$ from $x$ and $y$, so that there are no more multiples of $7$ or $11$ left in $m$ and $n$, which in-turn means the gcd is $1$.